# CRM 2011 oData query confusion

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I am very new to CRM development, i was trying to [follow this article](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/technology/microsoft-crm-2011-odata-examples/?lang=en), i am a bit confused about below code, please check:

```
var xp = Xrm.Page;  
function onLoad(context) {    
  var accountId = xp.data.entity.getId();

  var mostRecentQuery = "/XRMServices/2011/organizationData.svc/ContactSet? 
  $select=FullName,JobTitle,EMailAddress1,Telephone1&$top=1&$orderby=CreatedOn
 desc&$filter=ParentCustomerId/Id eq guid'" + accountId + "'"; 



  getContact(mostRecentQuery, "MostRecent");
  ....
  }
```

The above javascript function executes when **AccountForm** is opened. The first line gets the accountId. the next line is oData query. 
Now check the **ContactSet** in this query, **i am confused here, how we can retrieve the ContactEntity based on the GUID of AccountEntity?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

Actually there a **Lookup** 'Parent Customer' on ContactEntity, it represents the unique identifier of the account or contact associated with this contact,  so we can select an Account/Contact as the Parent Customer of a contact.

So this given OData query actually retrieves the top 1 contact where this account is referenced.

I hope its clear.